# One pixel difference in percentage width

Tags: css

There is coming a one pixel margin between two green colors, i couldn't find it. I'm using `display:inline-block` http://premiumvoices.nl/all-reviews

Comment: Welcome, if you want us to help you, you need to provide us with some code or perhaps a jsfiddle, not only the link of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove whitespace from between your divs. HTML is a semi-whitespace-sensitive language.

Think of it this way; if you had the text:

```
<span>Hello</span> <span>World</span>
```

Then the output would be "Hello World" with a space between the words, because there is a space between the spans.

When you are using `inline-block` the whitespace between your divs matters, and is becomeing that small gap that you see. In other words, this will have a gap:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

and this will not have a gap:

```
<div></div><div></div>
```

when `inline-block` is used.